# Cannot Resolve a 500 (Internal Server Error) Code

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I have run into a 500 error that I cannot resolve while practicing with making a To Do app with various lists & to do items that all have full CRUD options.

To Do List code:

```
class TodoList (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todolists'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    todos = db.relationship('Todo', backref='list', lazy=True)

const todo_list_input = document.getElementById('todo_list_id');
            document.getElementById('create_list_box_button').onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const list_title = todo_list_input.value;
                todo_list_input.value = '';
                fetch('/todolists/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'todo_list_id': list_title,
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Contet-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(jsonResponse => {
                    const li = document.createElement('li');
                    const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                    checkbox.className = 'check-completed';
                    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
                    checkbox.setAttribute('data-id', jsonResponse.id);
                    li.appendChild(checkbox);

                    const text = document.createTextNode(' ' + jsonResponse.description);
                    li.appendChild(text);

                    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
                    deleteButton.setAttribute('data-id', jsonResponse.id);
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = '&cross;';
                    li.appendChild(deleteButton);

                    document.getElementById('todo_lists_buttons').appendChild(li);
                    document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';

                })
                .catch(function() {
                    console.error('Error occurred');
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                })
            }


@app.route('/todolists/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todoList():
    error = False
    body = {}
    try:
        list_name = request.json()['list_name']
        todoList = List(list_name=list_name)
        db.session.add(todoList)
        db.session.commit()
        body['list_name'] = todoList.list_name
    except:
        error = True
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    if not error:
        return jsonify(body)
    else:
        abort(500)
```

I've tried changing variable names around throughout, no joy there, as well as a few other things to try to pinpoint the issue and am just out of ideas (still new at this) on what might be going on.

This only occurs when attempting to 'Create' a new To Do List. I can swap between lists and create/delete To Do Items no problem, it's just the Create List that isn't working.

To Do item code:

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('todolists.id'), nullable=False)

const todo_item_input = document.getElementById('description');
            document.getElementById('create_todo_box_button').onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const desc = todo_item_input.value;
                todo_item_input.value = '';
                fetch('/todos/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': desc,
                        'list_id': {{ active_list.id }}
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(jsonResponse => {
                    const li = document.createElement('li');
                    const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                    checkbox.className = 'check-completed';
                    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
                    checkbox.setAttribute('data-id', jsonResponse.id);
                    li.appendChild(checkbox);

                    const text = document.createTextNode(' ' + jsonResponse.description);
                    li.appendChild(text);

                    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
                    deleteButton.setAttribute('data-id', jsonResponse.id);
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = '&cross;';

                    li.appendChild(deleteButton);

                    document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(li);

                    document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
                })
                .catch(function() {
                    console.error('Error occured');
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                })
            }

@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    error = False
    body = {}
    try:
        description = request.get_json()['description']
        list_id = request.get_json()['list_id']
        todo = Todo(description=description)
        active_list = TodoList.query.get(list_id)
        todo.list = active_list
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        body['description'] = todo.description
    except:
        error = True
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    if not error:
        return jsonify(body)
    else:
        abort(500)
```

[Web app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3qeI.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7FXi.png)

Comment: you have spelled content in content-type wrong. That could be it.

Comment: Can you also show the definition of your List Model class?

Comment: Content misspelling wasn't it, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: any chance you can modify your server side code to return the error text, not just an `if not error`?

Comment: You pasted the same code again, it is not the List model class.

Comment: I am assuming you are using flask-sqlalchemy. That does session management by itself, do you have any specific reason for  closing the session in finally? If so then where is session being opened again.

Comment: Correct, flask-sqalchemy. As far as closing in finally, that is just what I picked up on watching videos and reading on my own, that each session needs closing, but my understanding of that could very well be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to put a more verbose exception in your code. Also, I think you can have the `error` check inside your try...accept

```
@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    body = {}
    try:
        description = request.get_json()['description']
        list_id = request.get_json()['list_id']
        todo = Todo(description=description)
        active_list = TodoList.query.get(list_id)
        todo.list = active_list
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        body['description'] = todo.description
        return jsonify(body)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)                  # ------- tracing
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
    finally:
        db.session.close()

    abort(500)
```